# ArcGIS Extract Values to Table crashes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geostatistical-analyst, error-999998

I am running the Extract Values to Table tool from the Geostatistical Analysis Toolbox in ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1 on Windows 10.
My inputs are a polygon layer with ~70.000 polygons and a raster layer with around 612,160,000 cells.

> Executing: ExtractValuesToTable HULL_polygon DGM10_slope
>   J:\XXX\HULL_slope.dbf
>   DO_NOT_ADD_WARNING_FIELD
>     Start Time: Mon Sep 30 08:18:12 2019
>     ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error.
>    Failed to execute (ExtractValuesToTable).
>   Failed at Mon Sep 30 19:49:28 2019
>   (Elapsed Time: 11 hours 31 minutes
>   15 seconds)

This happened numerous times and I don't see what the problem could be, since I performed the same task with much larger files in the past.

- I also know that the tool is working at first since I can open the
  table and I see entries that look as expected - if I don't open the
  table the tool might just crash as well.
- I also made sure they are
  in the same CRS.
- There are only polygons which are completely inside
  the raster layer.

So what could be the problem here?

Comment: You can't write 600 million rows to a dBase file -- it cannot exceed 2GB and still be valid.

Comment: @Vince which filetype should I choose then? Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I wouldn't write 600m rows to *any* format. If I need more than 50m rows, I'm doing something wrong and need to change my procedure.